# Explain Try-Except Error in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble running a try-except function(something_to_military). In my try section, I call another function(is_time_format) which I've thoroughly tested and works on every test case I've tried. However, whenever I call a value where suffix isn't valid, it doesn't produce the "Invalid Time Format". A friend of mine wrote a different code for is_time_valid but we have the same code for something_to_military. I know there has to be something wrong with my is_time_format code because it doesn't cause my something_to_military code to produce the "Invalid Time Format" whenever I use arguments such as "2:45 AMX". Does anyone know what's going on?

## PART 2: ASSERT HELPER

def is_time_format(s):
    """Returns: True if s is a string in 12-format : AM/PM

```
Example: 
    is_time_format('2:45 PM') returns True
    is_time_format('2:45PM') returns False
    is_time_format('14:45') returns False
    is_time_format('14:45 AM') returns False
    is_time_format(245) returns False

Parameter s: the candidate time to format
Precondition: NONE (s can be any value)"""
# HINT: Your function must be prepared to do something if s is a string.
# Even if s is a string, the first number before the colon may be one
# or two digits.  You must be prepared for either.
# You might find the method s.isdigit() to be useful.

pos1 = s.find(':')

pos2 = s.find(' ')

suff = s[pos2+1:]

x=s[:pos1]
y=s[pos1+1:pos2]
if type(s)!=type('str'):
    return False
elif x.isalpha == False:
    return False
elif y.isalpha == False:
    return False
elif s.count(':') != 1:       
    return False
elif x.isdigit() == False:
    return False
elif y.isdigit() == False:
    return False
elif len(x)>=3:
    return False
elif len(y)>=3:
    return False
elif int(x)>12:
    return False
elif int(y)>60:
    return False
elif suff !='AM' and suff !='PM':
    return False

else:
    return True
```

## PART 3: TRY-EXCEPT

def something_to_military(s):
    """Returns: the time in 24-hour (military) format if appropriate.

```
The function is the same as time_to_military if s satisfies the
precondition for that function.  If s does not satisfy the precondition
then this function returns 'Invalid time format'

Examples: 
    something_to_military('2:45 PM') returns '14:45'
    something_to_military('9:05 AM') returns '09:05'
    something_to_military('12:00 AM') returns '00:00'
    something_to_military(905) returns 'Invalid time format'
    something_to_military('abc') returns 'Invalid time format'
    something_to_military('9:05') returns 'Invalid time format'

Parameter s: the candidate time to format
Precondition: NONE (s can be any value)"""
# You are not allowed to use 'if' in this definition. Use try-except instead.
# Hint: You have to complete PART 2 before you complete this part.

try:
    is_time_format(s) == True
    return time_to_military(s)
except:
    return 'Invalid Time Format'
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined `is_time_format` (you didn't show it to us), it never raises an exception, it just returns `True` or `False`.

And the way you call it:

```
is_time_format(s) == True
```

… won't raise an exception either; you're just comparing either `True` or `False` to `True` and then ignoring the result.

What you want here is just an `if` statement:

```
if is_time_format(s):
    return time_to_military(s)
else:
    return 'Invalid Time Format'
```

---

Since you're not allowed to do that, you have to do one of two things:

First, you could rewrite `is_time_format` so it raises an exception instead of returning `True` or `False`. Basically, change every `return False` to something like `ValueError(f'{s} is not a time format')`, and drop the `return True` at the end. (And make sure to change the docstring to match the behavior, of course.)

---

Alternatively, you could write something that raises an exception on `False`. Which will be artificial and silly if done without an `if`, but there are options. For example:

- `{True: True}[is_time_format(s)]` will raise a `KeyError`.
- `assert is_time_format(s)` will raise an `AssertionError`.
- `1 / (1-is_time_format(s))` will raise a `DivisionByZeroError`.